# Comparar 1 variables con 1 TextField

Tags: java, string, botón, jtextfield

> Ola, estoy utilizando un textfield para que el usuario pueda poner el nombre que el quiera, presione el boton de "continuar", y la siguiente ventana se abra, y si el usuario no pone nada, osea que el textfield este vacio, cuando presione el boton de "Continuar" entonces le aparezca un mensaje que diga "Porfavor pon tu nombre".

Hasta aqui todo bien, lo que pasa es que si quiero hacer esto, necesito un boton, obviamente.

**El problema es, que cuando se presiona el boton, y el textfield esta vacio,se pasa a la siguiente ventana y no aparece el mensaje de "Por favor pon tu nombre".**

Intente hacer 2 TextField, el que se ve en pantalla, y uno que no se ve, ambos tengan el mismo texto al comienzo, y cuando se comparen, aparezca el mensaje, pero no me funciona, aqui esta el codigo

```
   fd.setBounds(30,200,620,35);  
   fd.setText("");
   fd.setBackground(new Color(127,127,127) );
   fd.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255) );
   add(fd);

   fd1.setSize(25,52);
   fd1.setVisible(false);
   fd1.setText("");
   add(fd1);

   setTitle("Sistema de Vacaciones");

 }

   //Aqui, quiero obtener con 2 string el textfield y poder compararlos en el "if"

   String Auxiliar = fd.getText();
   String Auxiliar1 = fd1.getText();

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c){

    if(c.getSource() == bt){

      if(Auxiliar == Auxiliar1){

        lb5.setVisible(true);
        
      }else{

        //El lb5 es el label que dice "Porfavor ingrese su nombre", si el usuario no pone nada
        //en el textfield, entonces le saldra ese label, si pone su nombre, se cerrara la ventana
 
        System.exit(0);

      }      
    }
  }
```

Segun yo, los 2 textField tienen el mismo texto, puesto que yo mismo les declare:

```
fd.setText("");
fd1.setText("");
```

**Pero cada ves que el usuario presiona el boton, se cierra la ventana, no importa si el TextField este vacio o no, siempre se cierra.**

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te complicaste más, aquí te dejo un ejemplo con el que te puedes guiar para aplicarlo en tu programa sin necesidad de ningun auxuliar, puede ser que antes estuvieras preguntando si el jTextField esta vacio en lugar de el texto del jTextField o algun error en las comparaciones.

```
public class Uno extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    JPanel panel;
    JButton boton;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField textField;

    public Uno() {
        setTitle("Verificar si esta vacio");
        setSize(250,250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.panel=new JPanel();
      this.boton= new JButton("Presioname");
      this.textField= new JTextField();
      this.label= new JLabel("Por favor ingrese su nombre");
      this.panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
      this.add(panel);
      this.panel.add(textField);
      this.panel.add(label);
      this.panel.add(boton);
      this.boton.addActionListener(this);
      this.label.setVisible(false);
      setVisible(true);

    }
    
    public static void main (String args []){
    Uno u = new Uno();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(this.boton)){

            if(this.textField.getText().equals("")){
                this.label.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

El programa basicamente hace lo que necesitas, si el jtextField esta vació cambia la visibilidad del Label, tu idea estaba bien al comienzo no era necesario el auxiliar.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás comparando las direcciones en memoria de los String y no su contenido.
Un String en Java es un objeto y para hacer la comparación del texto deberías ocupar: `Auxiliar.equals(Auxiliar1);`

Si haces `==` a un objeto, va a comprar sus direcciones en memoria y no su valor.

Comment: Creo que ya entendi, entonces, un String es un objeto, y para su valor se necesita equals, no ==.